# Java Collectors Streaming filter and .toMap when detecting case insensitve duplicates for various types

Tags: java, stream, collectors

I have a data structure that collates potential case insensitive naming clashes.

- caseInsensitiveDuplicates
- Think of the nested maps as a way of doing a compound key.
- The integer represents a type of data that may have duplicates,
- the first String is the uppercase version of the string
- the set that follows could contain any number of versions..
  .. so JEREMY: ['Jeremy', 'jeremy','JEREMY'] etc is plausible data.

The goal is to identify when the Set contains more than one entry. Upper and lowercase versions of data can co-exist, and I have to identify those cases. Hence this data structure.

- so the data N1 and n1 will be two entries keyed on the uppercase N1, and I am looking to get that back in the results.

There is a call to filter this via Streams:

- I have to work on EntrySet to keep keys/values together. I know that much.
- I want to return the same data structure I started out with (the type of caseInsensitiveDuplicates)
- I know I need to filter on the size exceeding 1.

(My actual code has an enum where Integer is, and a custom class where String is within the Set on the line where it's declared. See code below).

From initial data like so:

```
1 : N1 : [n1, N1]
1 : N2 : [n2]
```

My expected result would be a data structure with data like so:

```
1 : N1 : [n1, N1]
```

---

Here is a [link](https://code.sololearn.com/c1cY06pbmjI8) to a runnable version of the code

My initial attempt in the `filter()` part of the Stream was to use:

```
e -> e.getValue().values().size() > 1
```

That just returns everything

```
caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size(): 1
t1Dups.keySet().size(): 2
k: N1
v: N1
v: n1
k: N2
v: n2
N1 size: 2
N2 size: 1
---
k:N1
v:N1
v:n1
k:N2
v:n2
```

@Eritrean indicated the latest modification

```
e -> e.getValue().values().stream().allMatch(set -> set.size() > 1)
```

along with the syntactic sugar for the `Collectors.toMap()`

Thanks for that part.

From an attempt at debugging, the code currently prints:

```
caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size(): 1
t1Dups.keySet().size(): 2
k: N1
v: N1
v: n1
k: N2
v: n2
N1 size: 2
N2 size: 1
dupsAllTypes keyset was empty
```

---

I have posted a brute force non streaming solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901107/495157). But still would like to see if this is solvable in a more efficient way with Streams/Filters.

---

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class TestDupNameDataStructureFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> caseInsensitiveDuplicates = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> n1Set = new TreeSet<>();
        n1Set.add("n1");
        n1Set.add("N1");
        Set<String> n2Set = new TreeSet<>();
        n2Set.add("n2");
        Map<String, Set<String>> m1 = new TreeMap<>();
        m1.put("N1", n1Set);
        Map<String, Set<String>> m2 = new TreeMap<>();
        m2.put("N2", n2Set);
        Integer nmt = 1;
        caseInsensitiveDuplicates.put(nmt, m1);
        Map<String, Set<String>> temp = caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt);
        temp.put("N2", n2Set);
        caseInsensitiveDuplicates.put(nmt, temp);
        out.println("caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size(): " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size());
        Map<String, Set<String>> t1Dups = caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt);
        out.println("t1Dups.keySet().size(): " + t1Dups.keySet().size());
        for (String k : t1Dups.keySet()) {
            out.println("k: " + k);
            for (String v : t1Dups.get(k)) {
                out.println("v: " + v);
            }
        }
        out.println("N1 size: " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt).get("N1").size());
        out.println("N2 size: " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt).get("N2").size());
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> dupsAllTypes = caseInsensitiveDuplicates
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        //.filter( e -> e.getValue().values().size() > 1)
        .filter( e -> e.getValue().values().stream().allMatch(set -> set.size() > 1) )
        .collect( Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue) );
        if (dupsAllTypes == null) {
            out.println("dupsAllTypes was null");
            return;
        } else if (dupsAllTypes.keySet().size() == 0) {
            out.println("dupsAllTypes keyset was empty");
            return;
        }
        Map<String, Set<String>> dups = dupsAllTypes.get(nmt);
        if (dups == null) {
            out.println("dups was null");
            return;
        } else if (dups.keySet().size() == 0) {
            out.println("dups keyset was empty");
            return;
        }
        out.println("---");
        for (String k : dups.keySet()) {
            out.println("k:" + k);
            for (String v : dups.get(k) ) {
                out.println("v:" + v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if your data contains a `2: N2: [n2]`? The `N2: [n2]` should not be present, obviously. Does that imply that the `2` shouldn’t be present as well, as it would otherwise map to an empty map?

Comment: Correct. 2 shouldn't be present for that. But if 2: N2: [n2,N2] existed it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Collection API solution can be expressed as simple as

```java
Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> dupsAllTypes = new HashMap<>();
caseInsensitiveDuplicates.forEach((k1,kv) ->
    kv.forEach((k2,v) -> {
        if(v.size() > 1)
            dupsAllTypes.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new TreeMap<>()).put(k2, v);
    })
);
```

An equivalent Stream API solution would be

```java
Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> dupsAllTypes =
    caseInsensitiveDuplicates.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().values().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.size() > 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e2 -> e2.getValue().size() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
                    TreeMap::new)))
    );
```

This suffers from the lack of an API for a pair Stream, so we have to use a `Stream` of `Map.Entry` instances and insert `getKey` and `getValue` calls which isn’t as neat as `Map`’s `forEach` method.

Further, you want a `TreeMap` result for the inner maps, but there is no `Collector` accepting a map factory without a merge function. So we have to provide a merge function despite we know that there can’t be duplicate keys, as the source is already a map. Therefore, this solution provides a `(a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }` merge function.

This approach requires two `filter` operations. We could reduce the work by performing the inner map processing first, but this requires temporary storage:

```java
Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> dupsAllTypes =
    caseInsensitiveDuplicates.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
            e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e2 -> e2.getValue().size() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
                    TreeMap::new))))
        .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Here, the second filter is a trivial operation.

Note that for your task, the Stream API solutions are not only more complicated, they also do not provide any performance advantage. Basically, they do the same as the Collection API approach. Due to the described API limitations, they do even a bit more. They could run in parallel, but you’d need really large data sets to get a benefit from parallel processing.

---

If the original data is stored in mutable collections and you don’t need the original state afterwards, in other words, when you are allowed to modify the original collections, you can do the operation in place:

```java
caseInsensitiveDuplicates.values()
    .removeIf(map -> map.values().removeIf(set -> set.size() <= 1) && map.isEmpty());
```

This removes all sets not having at least two elements and if this leaves an empty inner map as result, this inner map is removed as well.

As a corner case, it would not remove an inner map if it was empty to begin with. If such maps shall be removed too, you have to use something like

```java
caseInsensitiveDuplicates.values()
    .removeIf(map -> map.isEmpty() ||
        map.values().removeIf(set -> set.size() <= 1) && map.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Nice answer and explanation. I will have a play with this in the morning and accept after giving it a try. On the inner function doing the comparison. Can you perhaps have an empty function - without the AssertionError()?

Comment: Since this function must return a result, the compiler will insists on a form that a) returns a value, b) throws an exception, or c) never completes at all (i.e. does an infinite loop). So it can’t be empty and obviously c) is not an option. So you can use `(a,b) -> a` or `(a,b) -> b` as an “I don’t care” option, but since this function should never be evaluated and entering this code would indicate a serious problem with the code (as a fundamental assumption turns out to be wrong), I prefer throwing an `AssertionError` which is precisely for flagging such situations.

Comment: the (a,b) - I got  is like compareTo from Comparable the use of AssertionError I just found bizarre. Reading again it's because there are no duplicates. because the map can't have duplicated keys. So why does Java even enforce the need for that. Seems truly counter intuitive. What is the use case when you would is what follows on from that?

Comment: The collector doesn’t know that our source data is from a map and does already have unique keys. There is also a `toMap` collector taking only two functions, suitable when you know that your keys are already unique. But it doesn’t let you specify which map type you want. So when we want a `TreeMap`, we have to resort to the overload that accepts a map factory, but there is none without a merge function argument.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to do this without resorting to building it manually. If someone else comes up with the correct way to do this with Streams, I will accept that as the answer.

Have revised this solution, thanks to @Holger for the following tips:

- `entrySet().forEach(…)` -> functional style: `forEach((k,v) -> ...)`
- [computeIfAbsent](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-computeifabsent-method-in-java-with-examples/)
- `map.keySet().size() == 0` -> abridged `map.isEmpty()`

---

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class TestDupNameDataStructureFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Core data structure
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> caseInsensitiveDuplicates = new HashMap<>();
        // Setup test data
        Set<String> n1Set = new TreeSet<>();
        n1Set.add("n1");
        n1Set.add("N1");
        Set<String> n2Set = new TreeSet<>();
        n2Set.add("n2");
        Map<String, Set<String>> m1 = new TreeMap<>();
        m1.put("N1", n1Set);
        Map<String, Set<String>> m2 = new TreeMap<>();
        m2.put("N2", n2Set);
        Integer nmt = 1;
        caseInsensitiveDuplicates.put(nmt, m1);
        Map<String, Set<String>> temp = caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt);
        temp.put("N2", n2Set);
        caseInsensitiveDuplicates.put(nmt, temp);
        // Sanity check data structure has intended data with some output
        out.println("caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size(): " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.keySet().size());
        Map<String, Set<String>> t1Dups = caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt);
        out.println("t1Dups.keySet().size(): " + t1Dups.keySet().size());
        for (String k : t1Dups.keySet()) {
            out.println("k: " + k);
            for (String v : t1Dups.get(k)) {
                out.println("v: " + v);
            }
        }
        out.println("N1 size: " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt).get("N1").size());
        out.println("N2 size: " + caseInsensitiveDuplicates.get(nmt).get("N2").size());
        // Core of solution
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Set<String>>> dupsAllTypes = new HashMap<>();
        caseInsensitiveDuplicates.forEach( (k1,kv) -> {
            kv.forEach((k2,v) -> {
                if (v.size() > 1) {
                    Map<String, Set<String>> temp2 = 
                        dupsAllTypes.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new TreeMap<>());
                    temp2.put(k2, v);
                    dupsAllTypes.put(k1, temp2);
                }
            });
        })
        // Debugging code
        if (dupsAllTypes.isEmpty()) {
            out.println("dupsAllTypes keyset was empty");
            return;
        }
        Map<String, Set<String>> dups = dupsAllTypes.get(nmt);
        if (dups == null) {
            out.println("dups was null");
            return;
        } else if (dups.isEmpty()) {
            out.println("dups keyset was empty");
            return;
        }
        out.println("---");
        for (String k : dups.keySet()) {
            out.println("k:" + k);
            for (String v : dups.get(k) ) {
                out.println("v:" + v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn’t dive deep enough to suggest a Stream alternative, but there are some striking issues even with basic collection usage, like iterating over a `keySet()`, to perform a `get` for every key instead of using the `entrySet()` in the first place: `for (String k : t1Dups.keySet()) { out.println("k: " + k); for (String v : t1Dups.get(k)) { out.println("v: " + v); } }` Instead of looping over the `entrySet()`, and dealing with `Map.Entry<…,…>`, you can also a `forEach` on the `Map`: `t1Dups.forEach((k, vSet) -> { out.println("k: " + k); for(String v: vSet) { out.println("v: " + v); } );`

Comment: This `forEach` on a `Map` is also much more readable than `entrySet().forEach(…)` (which again requires dealing with `Map.Entry`). So, unless you need to call `setValue` on the entry, just use `map.forEach((key,value) -> …)`. The old sequence of `get`-and-`put`-if-`null` can be replaced with a single `computeIfAbsent`. Applying both improvements results in `caseInsensitiveDuplicates.forEach((k1,kv) -> kv.forEach((k2,v) -> { if(v.size() > 1) { Map<String, Set<String>> temp2 = dupsAllTypes.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new TreeMap<>()); temp2.put(k2, v); dupsAllTypes.put(k1, temp2); } }));`

Comment: EntrySet gives you a common way to access the key and the values at the same level of depth in the code. Sometimes it helps for that. But for the initial streaming attempt it was important, because you have to consolidate on primary and secondary keys. with the detail count on the innermost set.

Comment: I don’t know which your “initial streaming attempt” is in your answer. I provided the simplified version for the code, I was referring to.

Comment: Got you now - the functional programming style - `forEach((k,v) -> ...)`

Comment: @Holger Just to clarify the confusion.  I posted the question and an answer (not what I was after, but the best I could come up with) - so when I read this initially I was placing an emphasis on why it would be so important for the question code.

Comment: As said, haven’t investigated enough to suggest a Stream solution but these collection idioms just jumped into my eye. `Map<String, Set<String>> temp2 = dupsAllTypes.get(k1); if  (temp2 == null) { temp2 = new TreeMap<>(); }` can be replaced with `Map<String, Set<String>> temp2 = dupsAllTypes.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new TreeMap<>());` Also, these `map.keySet().size() == 0` tests are weird. The map is supposed to have the same size as its key set, so why not use `map.size() == 0` or even simpler, `map.isEmpty()`?

Comment: keyset() size?  I used values().size()  This is what I started out with, and used - the only references to keyset().size() were in debugging comments to avoid null pointer exceptions etc. And I was predominantly testing for > 1 - so isEmpty is irrelevant - the debugging code -was what I deemed throwaway stuff - not in core solution. So it's a bit picky. But I get your point -thanks for the critique.

Comment: The compute if absent... where did 'key' come from? Just Java syntactic. I see now!

Comment: It’s the same key your passing into the method. The function can use it to compute the value, but in your case, the value does not depend on it.

Comment: Thanks - new one for me.

Comment: Regarding the other comment, I see two occurrences of `keySet().size() == 0` in your code, which are not comments (unless my browser is lying). Not that it matters much, `map.values().size() == map.keySet().size() == map.size()`, that applies to all cases. Making this code simpler serves two purposes 1) it’s easier to get what the code doing which makes it more likely to find a Stream API solution 2) if there’s no Stream solution, you still have a simplified Collection API solution.

Comment: Note that once you’re using `computeIfAbsent`, which does already put the new value into the map when necessary, the `dupsAllTypes.put(…)` is obsolete (I overlooked it myself in my second comment). So the operation simplifies to `caseInsensitiveDuplicates.forEach((k1,kv) -> kv.forEach((k2,v) -> { if (v.size() > 1) dupsAllTypes.computeIfAbsent(k1, key -> new TreeMap<>()).put(k2, v); }));` I’m currently checking the Stream API alternatives, but I can already say that they will be more complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239155/discussion-between-jgfmk-and-holger).